# Create an array-of-arrays from an array's elements

Tags: php, arrays, split

I'm looking for a function to take a simple array and create an array of arrays, without iterating through the original array (i.e., `foreach`)

For example, give this array:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

I want the result to be:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `$myArray = array_chunk($myArray, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk()` Documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

It will split an array into a multi-demential array of "chunks."  For you, you want every chunk to be 1 variable in size.

```
$Alphabet = array('a','b','c','d');
$Chunked = array_chunk($Alphabet, 1); // Chunk the Alphabet array in 1 size chunks
print_r($Chunked);
```

This will produce:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => d
    )

)
```